# How to show cursor pointer on button only

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="cursor-pointer" (click)="goBack()">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left my-arrow ml-3 mb-1"> </i>
    <a class="ml-1 go-back">Go Back</a>
  </div>
```

I created go back button, but it is clickable on entire row, to solve this I tried:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 cursor-pointer" (click)="goBack()">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left my-arrow ml-3 mb-1"> </i>
    <a class="ml-1 go-back">Go Back</a>
  </div>
```

But now col-sm-2 width also is more and it is clickable, I want to make only button clickable. Is there any proper way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a class="ml-1 go-back cursor-pointer" (click)="goBack()">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left my-arrow ml-3 mb-1"> </i> 
      Go Back
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```